# Is there an easy way in the Geth console to see the current numbers of blocks in existence?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there an easy way in the Geth console to see the current numbers of blocks in existence?

Same as "best block" at ethstats.net.

I tried admin.chainSyncStatus but it just returns 'undefined'